# List web url dir contents

Tags: python, urllib

I wanna list a external webpage's ulr's content. like i wanna list the content of this website `example.com/dir/dir/images/`

currently i can download an image from a page with:

```
urllib.urlretrieve(page_url,save_url )
```

But I want to list all images in a directory, or anything ells for that matter

I wanna use python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this can only work if the web server in question will serve you a directory listing when you navigate to that directory's URI.

If it does, typical directory listings have very simple markup, making them a prime candidate for various forms of web scraping. Otherwise, you're out of luck.

Comment: so if the web server does in fact allow this, how would i do that?

Comment: this will depend largely on the structure and formatting of your directory listing, but for your typical apache directory listing, finding each of the links on the page would be a good start. Have a google around for Web Scraping and Regular Expressions.